# Google Blogger/Blogspot onclick event in link will not pass to Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, events, google-analytics, blogger

I have the following snippet of code in a post in blogger/blogspot but I will not see this event in Google Analytics in Real Time.

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank" onclick="ga( 'send', 'event', {'Ebook', 'Download', 'ebook.pdf'});"><button>Download</button></a>
```

FYI the head in the blog includes the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
        ga('create', 'XXX', 'auto', 'blogger');
        ga('blogger.send', 'pageview');
      </script>
```

(id removed on purpose)

Does blogger block such info from flowing to GA?

Is there anything that can be done?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be using a custom tracker name, more about it here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers

You can try the following:

```
onclick="ga( 'blogger.send', 'event', {'Ebook', 'Download', 'ebook.pdf'});"
```

Comment: Hello, 

thanks for your reply. That didn't help unfortunately.

I should also mention that:

a. I don't see any relevant errors in the Chrome Developer Console
b. I don't have SSL enabled in the site (don't know if that's relevant)

I realize the JS is rather trivial and it should work so perhaps the problem lies somewhere in the on-click not being picked up by Google Analytics...
 
Any help is welcome.

Comment: Have you considered just editing your theme and adding Google Tag Manager to handle the click tracking?

Comment: Thanks @maggieto - I had a painful experience with GTM but I may have to revisit it...